# How to get API token if you are making a call using python scripts

Tags: python, api, salesforce

My Requirement: 
I need to fetch user details using the Salesforce API.

As per the Salesforce API documentation, I first need to authenticate users with necessary credentials than only I will get a token send to a **callback url** through which I can make other requests.

But the problem here is, I am making a python application that runs from console so I won't have any public urls which can be fed as callback url. In such scenario how can I access the API and fulfill my needs. Is there any alternatives way to directly access the token rather than authenticating and getting the tokens from the callback urls or any solutions to this problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems an old question but hope it helps someone.

In this case, you need to go with the salesforce username_password authentication. Please check this [Python Salesforce API Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58381676/python-salesforce-api-authentication) for more information.

In username-password authentication, you need to authenticate using the clientId, clientSecret, username, password + unique secret key. Once you get successful authentication, you will get an access token where you need to use this token for your Subsequent calls.

To generate a unique secret key, please refer to [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073796/salesforce-oauth-authentication-doesnt-work-with-username-and-password/58416933#58416933)

Sample Code to authenticate & get access token

```
import requests
import json

params = {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "client_id": "client_id", # Consumer Key
    "client_secret": "client_secret", # Consumer Secret
    "username": "username", # The email you use to login
    "password": "password + unique_security_key"}

headers = {'content_type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

r = requests.post("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", params=params, headers=headers)
access_token = r.json().get("access_token")
instance_url = r.json().get("instance_url")
print("Access Token:", access_token)
print("Instance URL", instance_url)
```