# Python Salesforce API Authentication

Tags: python-3.x, rest, soap, salesforce

I am trying to automate creating tickets in Salesforce. For this, I am using API with Python. I have got the Client ID and Client secret for my registered python Application. I have read many questions and as per the security purpose, I do not want to use the "user-password" flow for my script. Is there any way that I can only use "CLIENT ID" and "CLIENT SECRET" to get the access token where I can pass this access token in bearer header for other calls

```
import requests

params = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": client_id, # Consumer Key
    "client_secret": client_secret, # Consumer Secret

}

r=requests.post("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", params=params)

access_token = r.json().get("access_token")

instance_url = r.json().get("instance_url")
print("Access Token:", access_token)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll always need a SF user account. There's no way to just make a backend system talk to SF system. Salesforce treats everybody as user so you need to waste an account for "integration user" - but in return you can control access to tables, columns, functionalities just like you control real humans' access. This goes all the way down to the underlying Oracle database and database user privileges.

Whether you use OAuth2 flows (including client secrets) or maybe some [certificate-based authentication](https://blog.superpat.com/2018/01/25/salesforce-mutual-authentication-part-1-the-basics/) - there will be always some element of "username and password" required. Best you can do is to make sure your app doesn't need to see & store the password, instead showing normal SF login prompt and on successful login user is redirected to your app to continue with known session id...

There might be something you'll be able to automate more if your app and SF use same Single Sign-On but broadly speaking... You have to either let users login to SF via your app or create the tickets as some dedicated admin user (and then you store this user's credentials in your app)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and clear explanation. My app is just a python based script and whenever some event triggers, I need to authenticate to Salesforce and open the tickets. There is no User as a mediator to authenticate. Apart from not storing the password in script concept, is there any best way to authenticate in these cases? If there is only one case, is this one you are referring to? [Please check this](https://jereze.com/code/authentification-salesforce-rest-api-python/)

Comment: Whether you hand-craft the messages like in that blog post or use https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/ doesn't matter much. Yes, I'd say you need SF user's credentials. (what's a "ticket" for you? because maybe you could abuse a bit the Web-to-Case forms, there's a mechanism to push to SF Case and Lead records unauthenticated, if you only know the org's unique ID). As to how to store it securely - no idea. Maybe as environment variables? encrypted somehow in a config file? You'd need some Python gurus...

Comment: Hmm. It seems **user-password Auth** is the only way to programmatically authenticate to Salesforce. I am trying to open tickets in the Remedyforce. In this case, I will get the access token through User-password flow and pass the **access token** in **Bearer header** for further CRUD operations. Right? Also for the service account, we need to enable API permissions.

Comment: If you use REST then yes, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm is your friend. Unless all your Remedy users have SF account, then you could play with https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm. If you use SOAP API login call to get the session id you don't need client id + secret (but you still need username and pass). And yes, the account you use needs at least "API enabled" checkbox on the profile